# Error in configuration for I2S microphone

Tags: kernel, i2s, microphone

I follow [these directions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test#raspberry-pi-i2s-configuration) to set up the Raspberry Pi for an [Adafruit I2S microphone](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout). The line to compile the module fails with a missing script:

```
$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r )/build M=$(pwd) modules
make: Entering directory '/home/pi/linux-20565...c94ca877a099a3c9c5fa39a0380f3d16491'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/rpi-i2s-audio/my_loader.o
/bin/sh: 1: ./scripts/recordmcount: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:309: recipe for target '/home/pi/rpi-i2s-audio/my_loader.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/pi/rpi-i2s-audio/my_loader.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** Deleting file '/home/pi/rpi-i2s-audio/my_loader.o'
Makefile:1517: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/rpi-i2s-audio' failed
make: *** [_module_/home/pi/rpi-i2s-audio] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/linux-20565c94ca877a099a3c9c5fa39a0380f3d16491'
```

I tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766383/linux-scripts-recordmcount-no-such-file-or-directory) and was unable to compile scripts in the relevant directory:

```
$ make scripts
make: *** No rule to make target 'scripts'.  Stop.
$ pwd
/home/pi/rpi-i2s-audio
```

This is a follow-up question [on this other thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101203/how-to-force-compilation-of-kernel-with-rpi-source-for-i2s-microphone).

How can I compile the module to use the I2S microphone?